# Prove that $\frac {n!}{(k! 2^k)(n-2k)!} \neq {n \choose 2}$ for $\forall k \neq 1$ where $n \neq 6$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $$\frac {n!}{(k! 2^k)(n-2k)!} \neq {n \choose 2}$$ for $\forall k > 1$ where $n \neq 6$.

I have expanded it it seems to be not equal but couldn't find the proper logic.

Comment: for $2\le k \le n/2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac {n!}{(k! 2^k)(n-2k)!} = \dfrac{(2k)!}{(k! 2^k)}\dfrac {n!}{(2k)!(n-2k)!} = \dfrac{(2k)!}{(k! 2^k)}{n\choose 2k}$$

$\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k! 2^k)} = 1\cdot 3\cdot5\cdots(2k-1)$ is a positive integer strictly greater than $1$ when $k>1$

${n\choose 2k}\geq{n\choose 2}$ when $ k >1 $ and $2k\neq n-1,n$

So $\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k! 2^k)}{n\choose 2k} > {n\choose 2}$ when $ k >1 $ and $2k\neq n-1,n$

If $2k = n-1$(so $n = 2k+1 >3$), we have ${n\choose 2k} = {n\choose n-1} = n$, $\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k! 2^k)} = 1\cdot 3\cdot5\cdots(2k-1)\geq (n-2)$, it's easy to verify $n(n-2) > {n\choose 2}$ when $n > 3$

If $2k = n$(so $n\geq 4$), we have ${n\choose 2k} = {n\choose n} = 1$, $\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k! 2^k)} = 1\cdot 3\cdot5\cdots(2k-1)\geq (n-3)(n-1)$, it's easy to verify $(n-3)(n-1) > {n \choose 2}$ when $n >6$

Now verify the result for $n=4, k=2$ to conclude